# How do I Access One Column of a Peewee ForeignKeyField

Tags: python, mysql, flask, peewee, flask-peewee

I'm trying to access the id column of a ForeignKeyField to my UserAccount table through my Like table with various queries such as:
`if models.Like.select().where(models.Like.user.id==current_user.id,models.Like.post.id==post_id).exists():`

I've been trying to access the column id on User and Post. I've achieved this before in a Jinja template by looping through each row and accesing the foreign key through `model.Table.foreignkeyfield.foreignkeycolumn` like below:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{post.user.username}}
{% endfor %}
```

(user is a ForeignKeyField, username a column in the User table)

My question is: Is there a way for me to access a foreign key column without looping through the entire table???

**'Like' Model**

```
class Like(Model):
    post = ForeignKeyField(rel_model=Post, related_name='Like')
    user = ForeignKeyField(rel_model=UserAccount, related_name='Like')

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

Much appreciated - Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the `id` column, peewee should be able to figure it out in the query:

```
(Like
 .select()
 .where(
     (Like.user==current_user) &
     (Like.post == post_id)).exists():
```

Comment: Cool - just out of interest, say I wanted to select a different column through this approach (like the username column of the UserAccount table, how would I achieve that?)